# Reach a value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value, console.log, proto

I would like to reach the value 10 in `We` only.

I tried: `console.log(gauge.cache[0][0])` but the result is:

`We:"10"`

How to get only 10 ?

```
gvjs_N {iq: null, Kf: Array(1), hg: Array(2), Mr: null, cache: Array(1), …}
    Kf: [{…}]
    Mr: null
    cache: Array(1)
        0: Array(1)
            0:
                We: "10"
                __proto__: Object
                length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but my guess is `gauge.cache[0][0].We`. If so, this is an answer you should have easily been able to find elsewhere and you may want to spend some more time reviewing the fundamentals of Javascript.

Comment: I have already tried but it returns me "undefined"

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help you with how unclear and poorly written/formatted the question is. You will have a lot more luck if you edit your question to  provide clear details about what you are doing.

Comment: I can't format my sorry code

Comment: I would like to reach the value "10" of the key WE

I tried: console.log (gauge.cache [0] [0] .We) but it returns "undefined"

The result of: console.log (gauge.cache [0] | 0]) returns me We: "10"

I will need the console to return only "10"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
console.log(gauge.cache[0][0].We)
```

Comment: That's interesting... what about `console.log(gauge.cache[0][0]["We"]`

Or maybe try `console.log(typeof gauge.cache[0][0])` and make sure that that returns the value `array` ...because it seems like `console.log(gauge.cache[0][0].We)` should have worked if I'm understanding the code you put in right

Comment: I use google charts - gauge. console.log (typeof (gauge.cache [0] [0])) returns object

Comment: [Array(1)]
    0: Array(1)
        0: {We: "10"}

Comment: If it is returning an object then you should be able to accesses in the ways that have been described. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp to see if we've missed anything